# changing the width of the text input when hover

Tags: html, css

i am a beginner at CSS. i am trying to change the width of the input to `120px` when i hover over the search text. how do i do it? i have try few code, but it doesn't seem to work.

**html**

```
<body>
    <div class = "search-box">
    <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="type something">
    <a class="search-button" href="#">search</a>

    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover + .search-text{`
width:125px;
}
```

Comment: Use the linked question, and reverse the DOM order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without Javascript you will have to wrap your input element inside of a(anchor) tag something like this--

**try out the code below**

```css
a:hover .search-text{
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "search-box">
      
      <a class="search-button" href="#"><input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="type something">search</a>
  
      </div>
```

Comment: I hope this will help you Thank you!!

Comment: "when i hover over the search text", this works when hovering over the search field, not text.

Comment: actually now I have your issue you want to hover over text field now it's working fine!

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal not textfield, i want to hover over anchor tag `<a>`

Comment: @AbhinavK  my previous answer I fixed it for hover over anchor tag but you were still had issues!

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal this is fine but, still doesnt work. my `<a>` is not a container/parent so `a:hover .search-text` won't work

Comment: @AbhinavK please copy the whole code which I have fixed then try and then let me know!

Comment: @AbhinavK I hope you will understand!

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal i think i got it now! i missed to see that you have wrapped `<input>` inside '<a>' thanks a lot!

Comment: @AbhinavK I'm happy to see you got your answer and satisfied. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 1):

##### Css

There isn't a nice CSS selector that allows us to target a element when an other element is behing hovered.

There is a way, described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered), but that expects the element to exist *after* the hover element seen in the DOM. Your current HTML is reversed, so that wont work.

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to use `flex-direction` to reverse the DOM element so we can use the 'hack' described in the linked post.

Example:

```css
a:hover ~ .search-text {
  width:200px;
}

.search-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.search-button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "search-box">
  <a class="search-button" href="#">search</a>
  <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="type something">
</div>
```

**NB:** Since the `<input>` is getting larger, the mouse isn't hovering on the element anymore, therefor it will shrink again, letting the mouse back over the element, this causes the weird jumping effect.

---

##### jQuery

Of course we can create a jQuery based solution using the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events. This way we

- Don't need to change the DOM order
- Prevent the `<input>` jumping by checking on `mouseleave` on the `<input>` instead off the `<a>`

Example:

```js
let i = $('.search-text'),
    a = $('.search-button');
i.width(150);

a.on('mouseover', function() {
    i.width(300);
});

i.on('mouseleave', function() {
    i.width(150);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "search-box">
  <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="type something">
  <a class="search-button" href="#">search</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**CSS**

```css
.search-text:hover{
width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class = "search-box">
    <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="type something">
    <a class="search-button" href="#">search</a>

    </div>
</body>
```

**NB** : you are trying to decrease the width.

Comment: "when i hover over the search text", this works when hovering over the search field, not text.

Comment: @Sajid i want to hover over anchor tag not input tag

Answer (score 0):

From 0stone0 answer :)

```css
.search-box:hover > .search-text {
  width:125px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class = "search-box">
    <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="type something">
    <a class="search-button" href="#">search</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Uhmn, please add some details? Not sure what you're trying to achieve with this answer.

Comment: change the width of the input to 120px when i hover over the search text

Comment: OP means the literal 'search' text, not the input field.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.searchbox > input[type='text']{
  border : 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  outline: none;
  transition : 0.7s;
}


.searchbox > input[type='text']:hover{
  padding-right: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="searchbox">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not answers OP question, he want the input to enlarge when hovering on the search text~